# Is there a way to get "newsletter" digest of "good to knows" continuously active questions/answers?

Tags: discussion, community-digests

There are a lot of questions with high upvotes that are still relevant and have new answers / edits that are also highly upvoted despite being asked years ago.

I would consider these important or "Good to know" question and answers.

Is there a way to search for them or get a weekly feed of these "Good to knows"?

Comment: could you be specific about what qualifiers describe the questions you want to get notifications about? If you state something clear, I'm sure we can cook up a SEDE query for you.

Comment: @starball First of all, thanks for mentioning SEDE i wasn't aware of that. are there more api/api like tooling for stack exchange?

Answer (score 4):

The Community Digests feature seems like it could more or less fit this purpose for you; it's a weekly email that contains both new and old highly-rated questions from a specific Stack Exchange community/ site.

They have 3 sections, the second of which sounds most applicable: "Top new questions this week", "Greatest hits from previous weeks", and "Can you answer these questions".

You can subscribe to any site's digest and see previews of what they look like via https://stackexchange.com/digests.

[image: Screenshot of the Meta Stack Exchange digest tile in the digests list]

You can also see and manage existing subscriptions to newsletters from your user settings at https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/email/digests/current.

[image: Screenshot of the "Community Digests" pane in user email settings]